# Buttons to update jQuery datepicker by 30/60/90 days

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have your standard jQuery datepicker all default options.  What I am trying to add is add a .net or HTML buttons that will populate this datepicker with todays date + 30/60/90 days.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="followUpDate" runat="server" CssClass="datePicker" />

$(".datePicker").datepicker();
```

I'm not sure if I should use a LinkButton, or a Button.  I'm sure both would work, just not sure how to interface with the jQuery datepicker.

Comment: I updated my answer, please let me know if it is what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code I', showing you the basics of how to do it, it can be optimized and you can probably generate the days var on the server side, but wanted to show you the full picture

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
var today = new Date();
var add30Days = new Date();
var add60Days = new Date();
var add90Days = new Date();

add30Days.setDate(today.getDate() + 30);
add60Days.setDate(today.getDate() + 60);
add90Days.setDate(today.getDate() + 90);
var formated30date = (add30Days.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + add30Days.getDate() + '/' + add30Days.getFullYear();

$("#datepicker").val(formated30date);
```

EDIT: I see you are still inquring on this so I updated the code to make it fully functional:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
$('button').on('click', function() {
      var today = new Date();     
      var addDays = new Date();
      var days = parseInt($(this).attr("id").split("_")[1],10);
          addDays.setDate(today.getDate() + days);    
  var newDate = (addDays.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + addDays.getDate() + '/' + addDays.getFullYear();
    $("#datepicker").val(newDate);
});
```

See the new [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/D4AGz/)

Comment: Thanks, lemme play around with this to see if I can get it to work on my end.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a regular button and then a click event to change the input box value.  The datepicker should change automatically.

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function() {
  //code to make newDate string
  $('#datepicker_input').val(newDate);
});
```

Here is a fiddle of the code in action.  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kJUHv/)

Comment: If I set the date to today then click add 30 days, it sets the date to 08/05/2013 which is only about 26 days away.  Any idea why it isn't doing a full 30 days?